# NSUserDefaults, credentials removal on uncheck iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using below code for for saving the username password, credentials saved properly but the issue is when I again run the application, it shows the credentials in textfields but checkbox remains empty (i am using images to show the box checked and unchecked).
My questions are:
1. How can i save the state of checkbox if it is checked or unchecked and 
2. If it is unchecked how can i remove the credentials from nsuserdefaults.

```
- (IBAction)checkboxButton:(id)sender{
if (checkboxSelected == 0){
    [checkboxButton setSelected:YES];


    NSString *user = [userNameField text];

    NSString *passwd = [passwordField text];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setObject:user forKey:@"Username"];

    [defaults setObject:passwd forKey:@"Password"];

    [defaults synchronize];

    NSLog(@"Data Saved");

    checkboxSelected = 1;

} else {
    [checkboxButton setSelected:NO];
    checkboxSelected = 0;

    //Saving Username Password in file



}
```

}

thank you ... :)

Comment: you can use - (void)setBool:(BOOL)value forKey:(NSString *)defaultName
method of NSUserDefaults to save the state of checkbox button .Also for removing the credential you can use  
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults removeObjectForKey:@"Password"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can save the state of the checkbox in the `NSUserDefaults`.

To read do the following.

```
BOOL isChecked = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"loginCheckBox"];
```

It will return `NO` (false) if it is not set.
To set the state:

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:checkboxButton.selected forKey:@"loginCheckBox"];
```

To remove the values from the `NSUserDefaults` just set the properties to `nil`:

```
[defaults setObject:nil forKey:@"Username"];
[defaults setObject:nil forKey:@"Password"];
```

---

**Also I can strongly advice you to store the password in the keychain.**
since all the data saved in `NSUserDefaults` is stored plain text.

You can use the easy to [`SSKeyChain`](https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain) for accessing keychain api more easily.

Comment: can you provide me any good link for keychain tutorial/example, so that i would get it understand

Comment: Edited my post and added easy to use Objective-C class for accessing the keychain.

Comment: but checkboxbutton state is not getting saved

Answer (score 0):

for saving checkmark state you have to maintain a variable which has to be saved and read again to set the last state of checkmark and 
for removing values from `NSUserDefaults` : you can use:
`removeObjectForKey` method